# how to optimise this

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, arrays, matrices

Say you are given a matrix $M (A \cdot B)$ when $A$ is the number of rows and $B$ is the number of columns. Now we are free to pick one element from each column. Lets say these elements are $E = \{ e_1,e_2,e_3,\dots,e_b \}$ and $f(E)  = \max(E) - \min(E)$. Find the minimum value of $f(E)$.

I tried multiple but I can't think of any way to answer. Please help.

Comment: The absolute minimum value of $f$ is zero, when $\max(E)=\min(E)$

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-style tasks for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Label each element $m_{i,j}$ of $M$ with $(m_{i,j}, j)$ and sort all such pairs in non-decreasing order of the first element (the order on the second element can be arbitrary).

We will use a data structure that maintains a dynamic collection $D$ of $n$ elements and is able to insert elements, delete elements, report the maximum element in $D$, report the minimum element in $D$, and report $|D|$ in $O(\log n)$ time per operation. For example you could use an AVL tree.
In our application, this data structure will contain at most one pair $(m, j)$ per column $j$. If $|D|=B$ the elements associated with these pairs will represent a tentative solution $E$.

Moreover, maintain an array $A[1, \dots, B]$. The generic $j$-th entry $A[j]$ of $A$ will contain the pair $(m,j)$ currently in $D$, if any.
Initially all entries of $A$ are "empty".

As said before, the following algorithm will maintain a tentative solution $E$. Let $m^*$ be the minimum value of $f(E)$ encountered so far. Initially $m^* = +\infty$.

Proceed as follows:

- For each pair $(m, j)$ in non-decreasing order of $m$:

  - If $A[j]$ not is empty, delete $A[j]$ from $D$.
  - Insert $(m,j)$ into $D$.
  - Set $A[j] = (m,j)$.
  - If $|D|=B$ then let $(m^-, \cdot)$ and $(m^+, \cdot)$ be the minimum and maximum values in $D$, respectively, and update $m^* = \min\{m^*, m^+ - m^-\}$.
- Return $m^*$.

Clearly this algorithm takes $AB \log (AB)$ time. We now argue about its correctness.

Let $E = \{ m^*_1, m^*_2, \dots, m^*_B \}$ be an optimal solution, where $m^*_i$ is selected from the $i$-th column of $M$.
Consider the instant $t$ at which the last element $m^+$ from $E$ is added to $D$ by the algorithm (notice that, by construction, we have $m^+ = \max E$) and let $(m_1, 1), (m_2, 2), \dots, (m_B, B)$ be the keys in $D$.

It suffices to prove that, for each $j = 1, \dots, B$ we have $m^*_j \le m_j \le m^+$.
The inequality $m_j \le m^+$ is trivial, so we can focus on $m^*_j \le m_j$.
By our choice of $t$, we know that all $m^*_j$ must already have been processed by the algorithm at some time $t'$ that comes not later than $t$. Then, at time $t'$, $(m^*_j, j)$ was in $D$. The claim follows since the pairs $(\cdot, j)$ inserted in $D$ are monotonically non-decreasing w.r.t. the value of their first element.